# Symfony 403 Error

Tags: php, apache, symfony, osx-yosemite, http-status-code-403

I just installed Symfony on my Mac running Yosemite but keep getting 403 errors. This isn't just affecting the directory into which I installed symfony, but also sites in other directories that were previously working fine! So far I have tried:

1. Following the "Setting up permissions" instructions on the Symfony installation page... http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html ("Using ACL on a system that supports chmod +a" and "change the umask so that the cache and log directories will be group-writable or world-writable") so I guess the problem isn't to do with the log and cache files.
2. Updating apache config with...

   Require all granted
   Allow from All
3. Checking user permissions:

   Options Indexes MultiViews
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
4. Lots of killing and restarting apache

Still getting..

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /projectx/ on this server.

Anyone seen this problem before?

Many thanks

Comment: there are several places in `httpd.conf` that should be changed from `Allow from all`

Comment: If your apache server is 2.4, htaccess is turned off by default. Did you try to  display view by calling page directly : /app_dev.php ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for your suggestions, I figured it out. The problem was that I was putting my app in the apache doc root (symfony uses a different web server by default). I needed to create a virtual host (and tell apache to use the httpd-vhosts.conf in the first place)

This article had the answer...http://dab.io/posts/using-apache-for-developing-with-symfony.html

Thanks again!